# Extract Data from JSON object in angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I have this reponse as JSON object.

Object {auth_token: "60a483bc0b1bc4dc0231ff0b90a67be1dad6ef45"}
auth_token:"60a483bc0b1bc4dc0231ff0b90a67be1dad6ef45"
**proto**
:
Object

I want to extract "60a483bc0b1bc4dc0231ff0b90a67be1dad6ef45" from this object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you've assigned that response to a variable:

```
var someObject = {auth_token: "60a483bc0b1bc4dc0231ff0b90a67be1dad6ef45"};
```

You can extract the value by using object.key notation

```
var valueForKey_auth_token = this.someObject.auth_token;

console.log("valueForKey_auth_token", valueForKey_auth_token);
```

And you'll see this on the console

```
valueForKey_auth_token 60a483bc0b1bc4dc0231ff0b90a67be1dad6ef45
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! I got it! :)